# Stop Reminders App from sending emails every time a change is made on a shared reminder list

Tags: email, reminders

I have a shared reminders list with my wife. For the last couple of weeks any time she updates/deletes an item I get an email - however when I update she doen't get an email. She  is the owner of the shared list.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to stop these emails.

Any help gratefully received.

Alan

Comment: We are having the same issue. I have shared reminders with my husband and every time I add something he gets an email which is driving him crazy. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have not [registered and verified the email address](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE68) you are receiving the emails at as an alternate email address for your Apple ID (or you have [multiple Apple IDs](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/multipleaccounts/) and have registered the email address with the wrong one).